# Backbone's model.destroy() not working for SharePoint 2010 REST list items

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, backbone.js

I've got a SharePoint 2010 app I'm building that uses backbone.js to retrieve items from lists. So far I can .fetch() and .save(), but the .destroy() method just doesn't do anything. The success method returns undefined.

Here's my model. Notice that I'm setting the URL per SharePoint's specifications on how their REST API works.

```
app.model.Reservation = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url : function() {
        return this.get("Id") ? '/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Reservations(' + this.get("Id") + ')' : '/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Reservations'; 
    },
    parse: function(response) {
        return response;
    }
});
```

If I try **this.model.destroy()** nothing is returned, but if I use a straight $.ajax() call, it deletes fine:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: this.model.url(),
    contentType: "application/atom+xml"
});
```

I've researched a lot on how to reset Backbone's sync method, but to no avail. I've tried Backbone.emulateHTTP and Backbone.emulateJSON.

Comment: Have you checked the server logs to see what's different in the requests that your `$.ajax` call and `model.destroy()` generate? Have you set [`idAttribute`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) property on your model to `'Id'`?

Comment: Well the 'Id' field seems to work fine when I use it as the url in the $.ajax() call. But I just tried your suggestion and didn't see any changes. But to your first point...is there a way in something like Chrome developer tools to check what the $.ajax or .destroy methods are doing? I don't have access to server-side logs. Thanks!

Comment: Check out "XHR" under "Network" in the developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it's done:

In the view, use **this.model.destroy()** (like expected)

In the model, set `idAttribute: "Id"` (thanks [mu-is-too-short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short)). Also, change the url function to use `this.id` instead of `this.get('Id')`;

```
return this.id ? '/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Reservations(' + this.id + ')' : '/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Reservations';
```

And then add a sync method to the model:

```
sync: function(method, model, options) {
    var self = this;
    var methodMap = {
        'create': 'POST',
        'update': 'POST',           
        'delete': 'DELETE',
        'read': 'GET'
        },

        type = methodMap[method],

        // Default JSON-request options.
        params = _.extend({
            type: type,
            url: self.url(),
            contentType: "application/atom+xml",
            dataType: 'json'
        }, options);

    return $.ajax(params);
}
```

Note: I have now tested this with create, read, and delete. Update is next on my list, and it seems there will be some configuration to do there. I've taken some inspiration from the [Backbone.SharePoint repository](https://github.com/lstak/Backbone.SharePoint) for this solution.